# How to install previously-archived apps from xcode organizer to my iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, organizer

Xcode keeps an archive of all the versions of my apps that I've submitted to the app store in the 'archived applications' section.  I assumed using this I could install an old version of an app to my device, in order to reproduce any problems my client may have had with that particular version.

However, when I try to do this I get an error:

'this executable was signed with invalid entitlements, the entitlements specified in your applications code signing entitlements do not match those specified in your provisioning profile'

The original app was signed using our App Store distribution certificate, and I use the Organizer interface to re-sign it using our Developer profile.

- select the archived app
- select the version I want to test
- click 'share'
- select 'iphone developer' next to identity
- save to disk (saves the ipa file)
- then copy the ipa to the device using the little + button you see next to 'applications' on the screen you get when you select the connected device.

Then I get the error, and the app isn't installed.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong here? Or is there a different process to re-install an archived app to my device?

Edit: Thanks for the answers, I've solved this now. I wrote up the process I used if others want to do this http://pervasivecode.blogspot.com/2011/01/installing-archived-application-to.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot install an app by dropping it into iTunes when it is signed with the App Store distribution certificate. You need an IPA signed with an Adhoc certificate to do that.

Xcode can resign an archive with the second certificate but I don't think this resigning will overwrite the first certificate. But then, I never tried.

Comment: Ah, yes. got it! I was signing it using my *developers* certificate, which then doesn't allow it to be installed. Presumably only Xcode itself is allowed to install apps using the developer's certificate.   I created a new Ad Hoc certificate on the apple developer site, installed it on my device, and used the xcode organizer to re-sign my archived app using ad hoc, (Select archived app, version you want, hit 'share', choose the iPhone Distribution identity (ad hoc), save to disk), and now it works.   Thanks!